# Reformulation of min constraints with binary decision variable inside the min()?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to reformulate a mix integer problem with a binary decision variable lies within the min constraint.

That is ${x_1} = \min \left( {c,\frac{d}{\alpha }} \right)$ where $c$ and $d$ are two positive decision variable and $\alpha  \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}$ is a binary decision variable.

And also in the case of ${x_1} \le \min \left( {c,\frac{d}{\alpha }} \right)$ or ${x_1} \ge \min \left( {c,\frac{d}{\alpha }} \right)$ does a reformulation exist ?

My first attemp was ${x_1} = \left( {1 - \alpha } \right)c + \alpha \min \left( {c,d} \right)$ but the min() still persist

I am quite uncertain how to continue with this situation any help would be really appreciated !
Thank you very much !

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to remove the min? If you simply had $x_1 = \min(c,d)$ then that's what you have, impossible to simplify further. Are you perhaps talking about $c$ and $d$ being decision variables too, and you want to derive the MILP representation of the model?

Comment: Oh yes $c$ and $d$ are decision variable too, my mistake !

Comment: Then it depends on how these expression enters your model, i.e. if it is required that $x_1 $ is equal to the expression, or if it enters in a way that allows you to exploit concavity (i.e. you can relax to $\leq$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple non-optimized representation starts with the initial logic

$1-\alpha=1 \rightarrow x_1 = c$

$\alpha=1 \rightarrow x_1 = \min(c,d) = x_2$

The min is also a logic condition

$c \leq d \rightarrow x_2 = c$

$c \geq d \rightarrow x_2 = d$

Introduce two binary variables $\delta$ to represent the two cases (constrained to sum to 1)

$\delta_1=1 \rightarrow x_2 = c,c \leq d $

$\delta_2=1 \rightarrow x_2 = d,c \geq d $

You now have four binary condition implies linear condition which you can represent using standard big-M modelling

$q=1 \rightarrow f = 0 \Rightarrow  -M(1-q) \leq f \leq M(1-q)$

$q=1 \rightarrow f \leq 0 \Rightarrow  f \leq M(1-q)$

Since you asked about high-level languages in the comment, with the MATLAB Toolbox YALMIP (disclaimer: developed by me) you would write

```
Model = [implies(alpha, x1 == min(c,d)), implies(1-alpha, x1 == c)]
```

Comment: I get your idea but this is quite complicated, is there any high level language that automatically reformulate the min constraint without asking the user to do the hardwork T.T

Comment: Yes, YALMIP for instance will do most of the work here (although not on this particular for of the model since it really isn't well defined as you divide by zero)

Comment: Added a small hint about high-level form

Comment: Model = [implies(alpha, x1 == min(c,d)), implies(1-alpha, x1 == c)]
Wow thank you so much, I could not even believe in my eyes any more !. This Yalmip is awesome. This will reduce a lot of hard work and increase readability !